# Android studio(2022.3.1) is crashing and hanging my chrome and other applications. Memory error is shown. My laptop is HP-pavilion15-eg0xxx 16GB RAM

Tags: android, performance, crash, freeze, android-studio-3.0

I'm facing a frustrating issue with my Android Studio installation on my HP Pavilion 15 (model eg-0xxx) laptop. Despite having what I believe are adequate hardware specifications, Android Studio crashes frequently and sometimes even hangs other processes on my system.

Here are the specifications of my laptop:

**Model: HP Pavilion 15 eg-0xxx
RAM: 16GB
Storage: 512GB
Processor: Intel i5 11th Gen**

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. Android Studio crashes randomly during project builds or when running the emulator, and sometimes it leads to system-wide hangs that require a hard restart.

I'm at a loss for what could be causing this issue, especially with the hardware I have. Can anyone provide guidance on how to further diagnose and resolve this problem? I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thanks!

I've already tried a few troubleshooting steps such as:

- Reinstalling Android Studio: I've uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio multiple times to ensure there are no corrupt installations.
- Checking for Updates: I've ensured that both Android Studio and my operating system (I'm running Windows 10) are up to date.